# SD-Card not working but is...?

Tags: sd-card

I have a SD card that I removed from a system (Pioneer AVH-70 multitouch car radio that works on GNU software, for Citroen C1 / Toyota Aygo 2015, if I'm not mistaken) and that system is relying on this SD card to work, so when I remove it it doesn't work but when I put it back in it works.

So that means there's data on this SD card right?! So I want to adjust and tinker with the data on this SD-card, but every time I plug it in a PC/Mac or linux it doesn't read it, it doesn't even show up in Disk Management or in Disk Utilities. I've resetted the computer a couple of times, no help.

I even bought a navigational SD card I copied this card just to be sure I inserted into the radio then I removed it because it wasn't responding so I tried to read it and all of a sudden it didn't respond like the original.

Is there a workaround or am I missing software I can use? I already used Disk Drill but also this software does not see it.

Comment: What is 'this system' ? If its say linux or an embedded OS, its not necessarily using a file system either OS can read

Comment: @user1 That's a pretty generic description. Does that car radio have a make and model? That would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't read it"? Does it show up in Windows Disk Management? And what does it show as?

Comment: On Linux, I would begin with the output of `fdisk /dev/sd<LETTER> -l` and see what it says. Don't have Linux? Then fire up VirtualBox and install some distro and learn.

Comment: @Bib A live session should be enough for this purpose. A VM is overkill.

Comment: @user1, if it doesn't show up in disk management at all, I'm afraid you're adapter/connector for SD card to the computer/s (you're by chance using the same one for the PC and Mac?) isn't working. While it might very well be a system using some different file system, or partitioning, anyhow it should still come up in Disk Management (as RAW or something else.)

Comment: Then I'd double-check if you actually don't see anything added to Disk management when the card is connected.

Comment: It's not a good idea to answer clarifying questions and otherwise provide info in comments. That makes it very difficult to understand your situation, what you've tried etc; especially when comment threads get long. Better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769697/edit) your original question instead so everything relevant is readily available. I added now the new info you've provided here, and I'm deleting my comments to clear the picture.

Comment: I don't know macOS, but in Linux the first thing to check is `dmesg` just after you connect the card (or a cared reader with the card). This should tell you if the OS recognizes the hardware and if the card gets a node like `/dev/sdx` or something. Then `lsblk` to confirm.  The card not showing in disk management in Windows indicates that maybe it won't show in `lsblk` in Linux (for reasons I cannot guess); but the chances are `dmesg` will tell you *something*.

Answer (score 1):

I bet this is happening:

- [SD cards can be "locked" with a passkey on a hardware/controller level](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/sd-cards/tnsd01_enable_sd_lock_unlock_in_linux.pdf#:%7E:text=SD%2FuSD%20card%20lock%2Funlock%20operations%20enable%20the%20host%20to,with%20thecorrect%20password%20before%20sending%20other%20unsupported%20commands.).
- Your car radio probably has an embedded passkey that it's using to unlock/lock this SD card.
- Getting this passkey would likely require advanced techniques involving directly reading NAND or other memory/hardware on the car radio's motherboard.
- SD cards, if locked, power up in a locked state.  Erasing the key is possible by sending controller commands to the card (possibly requiring special hardware, mmc-utils may work if the PC card reader is MMC and not a USB device), but it also erases all data on the card.

Placing an SD card locked in this way in a PC card reader tends to be completely invisible to the OS, as though there were no card at all.  This is especially true if your SD card reader is USB attached.